# Angular 7 page gets unresponsive when url is directly visited in browser but works when navigated using anchor tag

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am working on a angular 7 legacy application which is developed awfully, and i am facing a very strange issue. I have a component which accepts a parameter and that component is used to verify the email. But if that url is visited directly it doesn't work, so i tried to navigate to the link with hardcoded id to verify email using anchor tag it worked. I've checked all the routes and guards and redirections, nothing is giving me any hint of this weird behavior.

```
-- app.component.ts
--- home.component.ts
---- verify.component.ts
```

So app components is where i have the router outlet for my components but verify component is nested inside the home component. I have tested by placing router outlet in home component as well, but no change. There is also login and register components nested inside the home component folder and they work fine even if accessed directly.

Following is home module routing

```
   const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'index', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'index', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterModule' },
  { path: 'verify/:id', loadChildren: './verify/verify.module#VerifyModule' }]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PaginationModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes),
    NgxSummernoteModule,
    Daterangepicker,
    NgxDropzoneModule,
    ShareModule,
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Following is verify module routing

```
const verifyRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: VerifyComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PaginationModule,
    FormsModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild(verifyRoutes),
  ],
  declarations: [VerifyComponent],
  providers: [DataService, NotificationService],
})
export class VerifyModule {}
```

Following is app module routing

```
 const appRoutes = [{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' }]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true, enableTracing: true }),
    SlimLoadingBarModule.forRoot(),
    PaginationModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    ShareModule,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Its been 3 days and i still have no clue, tried a lot of solutions, but this one is different because when i hit the url directly the chrome stucks and after few minutes it prompts that Page is unresponsive, exit or wait. Guidance please SO. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move the :id variable route to the component block:

```
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterModule' },
  { path: 'verify', loadChildren: './verify/verify.module#VerifyModule' }]
```

```
const verifyRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ":id", component: VerifyComponent },
];
```